# Not able to use the win32gui module from pywin32 in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pywin32, win32gui

I'm using Python 3.7 with Pycharm.  I've installed the `pywin32` package for this project because `win32api` isn't compatible with Python 3.7+.

```py
import win32con
import win32gui
```

I'm trying to import these modules with `pywin32` installed but this doesn't work.  The problem only started happening after I uninstalled and reinstalled Pycharm and had to reinstall all my packages for this project.  I'm using the exact same interpreter as I was before.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: Can you share an error message? What do you mean by "this doesn't work"?

Comment: @romaingz It's just a ModuleNotFound error for both win32con and win32gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post installation step to follow:

> To install pywin32 system files, run `python.exe Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install` from an elevated command prompt.

Did you run this command?

See also [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)