# The pywin32 libraries (win32gui, win32ui, win32con) show "unresolved-import"

Tags: pywin32, win32gui, win32con

I have downloaded Python 3.7 and 3.9 (both 64 bit) as well as VS Code to replicate the following code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WymCpVUPWQ4&t=1291s

However, when installing "pywin32" and then importing the packages to the code, I get "unresolved-import" on the three imports: win32gui, win32ui and win32con.

I have tried multiple installation methods, what is strange is that the code replicated from the link above works.

1. Tried installing via "pip"
   https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/
2. As well as downloading the executable program for installation from: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases
3. Including installing using the .whl files from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (with their respective Python version and bits) and then proceeding to the "post-installation" which was explained here:
   [Not able to use the win32gui module from pywin32 in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499197/not-able-to-use-the-win32gui-module-from-pywin32-in-pycharm)
4. From source Forge https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

And still, the error persuades. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong or if the versions used are currently outdated/not compatible.

I tried the 4 installations both in Python 3.7 and 3.9 with 64 bit executables/.whl files.

This is the code that I'm using:

As a side note, the code works just fine if the "hwnd" is set to "NONE" but if I comment this and use the line "hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')" it just shows a black screen even though the Calculator app is open.

I suppose it's because of the imports.

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import numpy as np
import PIL 
import cv2 as cv


def screen():
        w = 1920
        h = 1080

        
        #hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Calculator')

        hwnd = None

        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        #img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img = np.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (h, w, 4)

                # free resources
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
        #img = img[...,:3]
        #img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
        return img

while(True):
    
    sc = screen()
    resize = cv.resize(sc,(800,500))
    cv.imshow('idk',resize)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```